# Java graph plotting library

Tags: java

I have to draw a line graph for some inputs (x/y), what is the best java client library for graph plotting

Answer (score 3):

JFreechart is a good option for client side graph generation (or serverside for that matter):

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html